# bash: laravel: command not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am Using my own Machine Kali Linux 2.0 Debian x64 . Now, i have Installed Laravel in my directory structure like 
`/opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-larvel/`

Inside the Learning-laravel folder i have Installed my Laravel files, and also i installed composer. So when i go to `http://127.0.0.1/learning-laravel/public` . I see a See a White Screen and in Between it is written "Laravel 5", which means the Laravel GUI Setup is fine.

Now, to create a new file for Laravel, when i open my Terminal and type 
`laravel new xyz` 
then it gives me a error which says `bash: laravel: command not found`

Now, how can i fix the error.. I have researched about it by setting PATH to bashrc. But i am not getting it fixed right. Additionally when i type in my command `composer -version` then also it says `bash: composer: command not found` but i have Installed composer on the folder learning-laravel itself. 
I could also see files like composer.phar there in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-larvel/`

Any help would be extremely thankful.

Comment: what new file for laravel? if you have laravel installed, `php artisan` is the cli command to interact with it.

Comment: @lagbox I meant in General that if i type the command `laravel` then it shows me Command not found. The command `laravel new file` is command to make a New File through CLI which is what i saw in this video of Devdojo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--9I5wqXgUM

Check the first 1 min of the Video.

Comment: you have to fix your composer issue first.. you should run it as `php composer.phar ...`

Comment: no that command creates a new project. have you downloaded the laravel installer ?

Comment: Also ensure to add composer to your PATH, bashrc is the best place

Comment: @Digitlimit Could you Provide Me the Commands for Adding it to bashrc. Because i used `export PATH="$PATH:~/opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-laravel/vendor/bin/"` which didn't worked for me

Comment: Open bashrc. Use `vi ~/.bashrc` then type this towards the end of the file `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

Comment: Save and exit, then run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Digitlimit I have Installed Composer Globally in my Linux. So whenever i type `composer --version` it prints out me version. So composer is actually solved. But Laravel has not been Installed globally. I went to Bashrc and followed the Steps you told. But it doesn't work .. To cross verify i wrote command `cd /.composer/vendor/bin"` it worked, which means Path is alright. But still laravel command in Terminal dont work .

Comment: You need to install Laravel installer. But wait a minute. Why are you still running Laravel command when you have successfully create a Laravel project, are you trying to create another project?

Comment: @Digitlimit I am new to Laravel. When i open `http://127.0.0.1/learning-laravel/public` then i can see Laravel 5 written on a White screen which shows Laravel is Installed in the Folder and i have tested some codes which worked fine. I am not aware of a Installer separately for Laravel. If you know, share me the Link. Moreover, i used the command `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` on My Terminal, after it Fetched the Dependencies then also laravel from CLI doesn't work. If you know other Installer then share the Link.

Comment: You no longer need to run Laravel command ...to create new file. Are you trying to generate a controller if yes you `php artisan` commands

Comment: @Digitlimit Yes, I am trying to generate controller and php artisan works on my XAMPP too. So, one more thing, whenever i want to make a new project. Let's say File uploader , then do i have to go to my `public` folder , Make a directory and use command `php artisan serve` to start the server?

Comment: No. You don't have to run php artisan serve nor create any folder in public folder, create your controllers and models. Please check the Laravel documentation

Comment: i think you need to see less stupid videos and read more docs

Answer (score 2):

As the composer official [getting started](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) page points out:

> There are in short, two ways to install Composer. Locally as part of
>   your project, or globally as a system wide executable.

if you wanna do `composer --` or `laravel --` in command line, you wanna install them globally.

Check out the following links:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#install-laravel

Comment: Thanks, i installed composer globally now. So when i type `composer --version` in my Terminal it gives me Version. But when i went to Laravel Documentation which you provided and i ran the command `composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist` and it shows it got installed succesfully and then i ran `laravel --version` then it shows me again "Bash command Laravel not found". Any method to get over it please?

Comment: That's prob because laravel is still not installed globally. `composer create-project` is used to create new projects from an existing package. You should prob use `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`. Also checkout: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project

Comment: As per you told, i have ran the Command `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1` as mentioned in those documentation, it fetched all the Repos/ files . But again, when i type simply laravel in my Terminal. It shows command not Found, so do you think, i should install it's PATH as Environmental Variable. ? Because i tried `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` too in Bashrc . But problems is the same :(

Comment: Yeah, I would def check the environmental variable path. Also, this is mentioned in the laravel docs. "Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system." I suggest you check again if your PATH is correct, and it's correctly set, by entering `echo "$PATH"`. Also, to make these changes permanent, you should add that to your ~/.bash_profile file. `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: `echo "$PATH"` shows `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: Then it's not correctly set. Try this: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc`, after that you wanna reload .bashrc `source ~/.bashrc`. The output of `echo $PATH` should look something like this `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/web/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin
`, with `~/.composer/vendor/bin` in it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Apparently, the composer exists in path ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin when running as super user. Therefore, replacing the paths which were described above by this, and it should work. Hope it helps.